# Transaction with inserts retried due to simultaneous select

Tags: transaction-isolation, cockroachdb

I am running into an issue with transactions in cockroachDB.

Periodically, a table is rebuilt using external data. My approach is to drop the table and re-populate the table from scratch within a transaction.

I noticed that if a `SELECT` statement is issued on the same table while the transaction is ongoing, I get a `TransactionRetryError`. After some research I realised I should use [cockcroach-db](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-go) so the transaction is retried automatically.

This works great in most cases, but when the reads keep coming in, cockroachDB eventually gives up with a `TransactionAbortedError`, specifically `ABORT_REASON_PUSHER_ABORTED`.

I realise that the automatic retry is just a bandaid for my issue. What I don't understand is why a read on the table causes the DB to retry the transaction inserting data into it. My guess would be that it has to do with [serializable isolation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/acid-rain/). If this is the case, I am looking for suggestion on either how to change my update logic or any other suggestions on how to solve this issue. I am fine with the read returning 'stale' data, as this is what is happening now anyway since the update gets aborted.

Answer (score 1):

If stale data is an option, you could use utilize [As of System Time](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/as-of-system-time.html) to read in the past in order minimize contention.

Also, Our 20.1 release introduced [Select for Update](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/select-for-update.html#:%7E:text=The%20SELECT%20FOR%20UPDATE%20statement,locked%20the%20rows%20to%20finish.) which is used to order transactions by controlling concurrent access to one or more rows of a table.

It works by locking the rows returned by a selection query, such that other transactions trying to access those rows are forced to wait for the transaction that locked the rows to finish. These other transactions are effectively put into a queue based on when they tried to read the value of the locked rows.

Check it out and let me know if it helps!

Matt

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include [example] of your code  the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].